# AJAX error checking

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have just started working with AJAX. I have one query regarding error checking which parsing XML data in java script. Actually i am creating XML file dynamically using C code. Some time it is givint me error that "unable to read child node" on following line. **xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue**. So before using this line is there any way to check whether my XML data has all the tags which i am looking for. So i can check and take appropriate action.

I know, I should provide appropriate tags while creating XML file. But if i miss some times then i wants my java script should check that.

Part of code i am using to read XML.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml?"+ Math.random(),false);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please consider taking the time to format your code. It's not hard and it really helps us to understand it easily. I've done it for you this time, but it would be really helpful to get into the habit for future questions.

Comment: Sorry...Next time i will be careful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one way is to

```
var to = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0]
document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = to && to.childNodes.length ?  to.childNodes[0].nodeValue : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `onreadystatechange` function.

```
var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml?"+ Math.random(),false);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
          document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

Make sure that you aren't trying to learn AJAX from a source like `w3schools`. Use the MDN for [learning AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) or anything JavaScript.

Comment: @VinayPatel I recommend using `.children` instead of `.childNodes` as `.children` only includes element nodes and `.childNodes` includes both text and element.